# libnotify error GLib.Error: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, libnotify

I am getting this error. Any idea what is wrong?

```
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init("App Name")
Notify.Notification.new("Hi").show()

GLib.Error: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
```

(using latest Raspbian on Raspberry Pi)

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install notification-daemon` fix your problem?

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't fix it :(    There is the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved it: :)

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-cil-dev
```

Comment: I got this during installation process: "no executable /usr/bin/cli found, but continuing anyway". Should I worry about it? Anyway I still get error: "Error showing notification:GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files"

Comment: it's cil not cli.

Comment: The context here is Python. Any `*cil*` package fetches mono. This feels much much overkill. `sudo apt-get install notification-daemon` fetches one of many options (like `notify-osd`, `lxqt-notificationd`, `dunst`, `mate-notification-daemon` or `xfce4-notifyd`). Depending on your desktop environment, you may prefer to just pick one of those options directly instead of letting apt choose.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that the package `notification-daemon` does not install any package listed under `Provided by:`. On my Debian-bookworkm Lxde desktop, it said about `notification-daemon`:

```
Provided by: awesome, cinnamon, dunst, gnome-flashback, gnome-shell, lomiri,
             lxqt-notificationd, mako-notifier, mate-notification-daemon,
             notify-osd, phosh, plasma-workspace, python3-jarabe, xfce4-notify
```

but none of these packages were actually installed - despite `notification-daemon` having been installed previously.

You may need to install one of these packages. I have chosen `dunst` and it worked fine.